# Install basic packages (libpci-dev, vim) on Debian Wheezy after LTS ended?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I'm trying to revive a very old system with debian 7, an rtai kernel, and linxCNC. I can't upgrade to something supported because this is the latest image LinuxCNC has with an rtai kernel, the newer images have worse latency performance and my system's latency is already borderline.

Everything is working happily except I need to install libpci-dev and apt can't find it, even though I have my sources pointing at `http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib`.

Is there some other way to access these? Is there any sort of archive for "just give me the repository as it existed in 2013, forget security updates?" This system will be offline forever as soon as it's configured.

I also tried building pciutils from source which I'm under the impression contains libpci-dev, and that installed successfully (I have setpci and stuff now) but the Makefile I'm trying to use still can't find libpci or pci/pci.h.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you post the output of `apt-get update && apt-get install libpci-dev`.

Comment: From an IT security point of view using an OS which is EOL sounds like a nightmare. Using plain Debian with a [PREEMPT RT kernel](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=linux-image-rt&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) is not an option? At first sight the [RT performance numbers on the LinuxCNC website](http://wiki.linuxcnc.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?Latency-Test) look pretty similar to what I'm used to from Debian 10+RT kernel.

Comment: Direct links to Debian 7's `libpci-dev`: [32-bit i386 version](http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pciutils/libpci-dev_3.1.9-6_i386.deb), [64-bit amd64 version](http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pciutils/libpci-dev_3.1.9-6_amd64.deb).

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://snapshot.debian.org/ (Debian package archive), pick a Wheezy snapshot and point your `sources.list` to it. Then you will be able to install old packages from that specific snapshot.

There may be quirks you have to deal with on dated systems, like manually installing `apt-transport-https` package or specifying `[check-valid-until=no]` in `sources.list`.